# Replace const value at compile time

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a way to read content of a file at compile time and replace value of a const with it:

```
public class MyClass {
  
 [LoadFromFile("/myFile.txt")]
 public const string MyConst = "";

}
```

This will read content of file `myFile.txt` (probably using `File.ReadAllText` or anything else) in directory relative to the working directory, content of this file could be for example:

```
Hello world
```

And in compiled assembly `MyClass.MyConst` would return `Hello world`.

Research led me to https://github.com/Fody/Fody and to "assembly weaving". How would you approach this problem? Are there any other ready to use solutions for this? I'm using .NET 5.

Comment: A root relative file reference would seem very problematic.

Comment: It might be helpful to explain why you want to load a "const" from a config file in the first place. Maybe the heart of the problem is that you should be using `IConfiguration` and dependency injection instead of getting a global constant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use an embedded resource, and then make `MyConst` a

```
public static readonly string MyConst = ReadResource("MyFile.txt")
```

See [How to read embedded resource text file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3314140/613130) (note that the `ReadResource` in the response can be made `static`).

I think that wasting time including Fody (and studying it, and following it through versions) for such a thing is foolish.

Answer (score 0):

not a const, but using using https://github.com/Fody/Resourcer you could embed `myFile.txt` as a resource then do

```
var myFileContents = Resource.AsString("myFile.txt");
```